# How to deal with live app that has frequent updates (winforms/clickonce)

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a situation where my app is being used and I'm adding features in nearly real time.  I end up get bug reports about already fixed issues because the users have not restarted.

A further complication is that people don't all understand that restarting an application and closing, then re-opening a modeless dialog are different things, and they also feel like it's "a pain" to have to restart too much.

QUESTION: Is it possible to programatically check for new versions of a WinForms click once application (web deployed on local intranet) and then display a button that will effectively get the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article on MSDN showing how to do programmatic updates to a ClickOnce app will help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add code to your application that periodically checks for updates(or at startup/exit) and force certain actions. A good guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).